# How can I solve an issue with app thinned process in Expo app?

Tags: ios, expo

I'm facing this issue:

> While processing your iOS app, App 1.0.2(1), errors occurred in the
> app thinning process, and your app couldn’t be thinned. If your app
> contains bitcode, bitcode processing may have failed. Because of these
> errors, this build of your app will not be able to be submitted for
> review or placed on the App Store. For information that may help
> resolve this issue, see Tech Note 2432.

I created my app using Expo and I'm building the app using `expo build:ios` the process finish successful. I'm using Transporter to upload to Apple Connect Store and that is going ok too.

After the app get's to the store I'm getting the email that it failed because of the app thinned.

Is there any advice for this? Also is there anyway to debug this to see where is the issue to fix it?

**Edit**:
Just a note, I also used `eas build` that provides Xcode Logs and it does not work neither.

Is there an issue with Expo building process or it is Apple store does not like how Expo is building the apps?? How can I request to Apple team for the logs, so I can know what is failing for them.

Comment: The thing is my first version works fine in Apple. Store Connect, I'm doing a building now almost exactly the sam code I had in the first version. Let's see what happen.

Comment: I checked the info.plist with the utility command and it is okay, no issues on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there was a breaking change in the App Store. To counter that Expo team removed bitcode from the Classic Build process (expo build:ios). So build and upload your app again now.

Reference: https://status.expo.dev/incidents/c52fybftz9z3